# Section number without section name on page

Tags: spacing, sectioning

This gives me a large heading that says "something", and updates the numbering:

```
\begin{document}
\section{something}
\end{document}
```

This gives me a heading without updating the numbering:

```
\begin{document}
\section*{something}
\end{document}
```

I want to update the numbering without having any text. I cannot do this:

```
\begin{document}
\section{}
\end{document}
```

Because that is giving me an error with spacing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome! Does `\stepcounter{section}` give you what you want?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yep! Thank you!